# Handle multiple version of code by AOP Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

We are migrating an old application to web application using Spring Boot.

The web server exposes Soap web service endpoints which supports different 13 versions of wsdl (from V1-V14 excludes V13), and there're some changes in validation layer of the code (Controller -> Validation -> Business..) that alter depend on the request version.

Note that the validation layer involves business logic and interaction with external systems.

Currently we have been finished the latest version V14 latest business code. And now we are finding a way to intergrate the other 12 versions into the code base. We plan to use Aspect Oriented Programming provided by Spring to handle that.

There're 3 parts of the solutions:

- annotations and aspect to handle method which decorated by annotations
- version specific business classes
- wrapper business class which call multiple version business classes

First we create some annotations to specify which version the code is refering to.

```
public @interface SpecificVersion14{}
public @interface SpecificVersion12{}
```

And the aspect is created to handle method that decorated by those annotations.

```
public ValidationAspect {
    @Around("annotations(SpecificVersion14)")
    public Object handleSpecificVersion14(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
        if(isVersion14) {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Around("annotations(SpecificVersion12)")
    public Object handleSpecificVersion12(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
        if(isVersion12) {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then apply to business code, for example here we have business to validate phone number which specific by V12 and V14. Because the AOP uses proxy class so we create new bean and annotate the validate function by the annotations above.

```
@Component
class ValidatePhoneNumberV14 {
    @SpecificVersion14
    public AlertMessages validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {}
}

@Component
class ValidatePhoneNumberV12 {
    @SpecificVersion12
    public AlertMessages validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {}
}
```

Finally the ValidatePhoneNumber will hide the version logic for its clients.

```
class ValidatePhoneNumber {
    private ValidatePhoneNumberV14 validatePhoneNumberV14;
    private ValidatePhoneNumberV12 validatePhoneNumberV12;

    public AlertMessages validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        validatePhoneNumberV14.validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);    // get called if V14
        validatePhoneNumberV12.validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);    // get called if V12
    }
}
```

(The code can be refactored to make validation stop when it reachs the desired version but it's not important here in the question)

Finally the main validation flow uses only one validator for phone number

```
class ValidationContact {
    private ValidatePhoneNumber  validatePhoneNumber;
    public AlertMessages validateContact(Contact contact) {
        validatePhoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber(contact.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach? Or are there better ways of solving this?

Comment: You are introducing a lot of magic to merge your existing production code. Magic can break. Is this worth the effort?

Comment: We have not found better approach since the changes are in multiple locations (the old code use branching if/else) and the code of latest version already stable, the AOP seems to be the less impact compare to the traditional way (abstract and inheritance)?

Comment: As Java has Functions with friends you could use those to provide functionality that can be called at each version specific point (think lambda expressions).  Then have a version specific configuration class that can provide those where needed to the calling code.

Comment: I will try that approach, Thank you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: To me your question is unclear. the explanation is ambiguous, the code in `ValidatePhoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber` (horrible name repetition, BTW) calls multiple validators, the aspect does nothing meaningful but proceed to the original code and there is no explanation where `isVersion14` etc. come from inside the aspect. It is as if you deliberately removed all details necessary to really understand your big pile of boilerplate code. For now the only thing I can say is that my feeling says this is way over-engineered. For example, why not use one annotation with the version as a parameter?

Comment: Sorry @kriegaex since I omitted some details,
My idea for this implementation is to use AOP for checking request's version before the version specific code is run.
Yes only one annotation with version parameter should be used.

Comment: I understand your idea, but not really your code if you don't update it. Feel free to also upload a minimal version reproducing your situation on GitHub. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just use dummy classes where you would in fact call real web services, dummy package names etc. I am not talking about original internal code, just something to run and analyse which resembles your situation as closely as possible.